# I have 12 cups of tomatoes, but my recipe calls for 10. What do I add?

Tags: tomatoes

I'm making salsa, and the recipe calls for 10. What do I add to make this turn out?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! If you can include the full recipe and a brief explanation about why you need to use all 12 cups, that'd likely help us understand the question better. While I could understand confusion if you have too little of an ingredient and need to reduce the recipe, I'm not quite sure why you need to use all 12 cups. Thanks!

Comment: It calls for 10 whole tomatoes, or 10 cups of tomatoes?  If the latter, what's stopping you from just following the recipe, and using the rest of your tomatoes in something else, like a salad.  (Or if they're canned, heuvos rancheros or something else the next day.)

Answer (score 20):

Without seeing the recipe the only way we can advise you is to give you a few general options:

1. **Don't use all 12 cups of tomatoes.**
   You say you're making salsa, which generally calls for fresh tomatoes. If that's the case, just don't use them all. Set aside two cups worth and go ahead with the recipe as written. This is likely the simpler option in that it doesn't require math.
2. **Use them but don't change the recipe.**
   While 20% extra is a good amount, salsa is generally the sort of thing that's pretty flexible and you're going to do a lot of adjusting to get it to taste the way you want anyway. Prepare it to the recipe with the extra tomatoes and adjust the taste at the end.
3. **Scale everything up by 20%**
   You have two extra cups over 10 cups, which is 20% more tomatoes. If you multiply all of the amounts in the recipe by 1.2, you should get an exactly scaled-up version of the recipe. This can get a bit weird if a recipe calls for things like whole eggs (which I'm assuming this does not) but as noted in point 2, the precision of the recipe amounts is unlikely to matter much.

The key takeaway here is that it's salsa - that's a pretty flexible thing, to be honest. The spice level of the peppers you use will vary drastically based on various factors, even within a single variety. Similarly, the flavor of the tomatoes and onions can be quite different depending on which types you use, so you're never going to get exactly the same thing twice in a row.

The important thing with recipes like this is to recognize that you can just wing it a bit and that you want to get to something you like the taste of, not something that's precisely followed a recipe.

Comment: 4. Prepare the recipe with 10 and then add the extras at the end if you think it can handle more tomatoe.

Comment: "Don't use all 12 cups of tomatoes."  This is so obvious that OP must not have explained enough in her question.

Comment: @RonJohn Sure - which is why I asked for more details to be added to the question... but it's answerable even without them.

Answer (score 7):

It’s all about ratios.

If you want to use your original recipe, note that 12 instead of 10 cups means an increase of 20%, or 1/5. If you increase all other ingredients by the same ratio, you get the same salsa, just more of it.

If you, for example, cut the tomatoes by accident and *don’t* want to make more salsa (or don’t have more of the other ingredients at hand), just leave the extra 2 cups out and use them in another dish.

You can even freeze the leftovers. For cooked dishes like pasta sauce, it shouldn’t matter whether you use fresh or frozen tomatoes.

---

For all other options, like altering your recipe, we’d need more details.